# Query Opportunity join on Partner account lookup (Join two quries)

Tags: soql, opportunity, account, partner

I have two queries, how can I join both together into one SOQL?

```
SELECT o.Partner_Account__c, o.id, o.name, o.Account.Id,  from Opportunity o
SELECT a.id, a.name from account a where a.id = my_Partner_Account__c
```

Partner_Account__C is id of Account object, I want to get PartnerAccount id/name in the opportunity query.

Opportunity object has two Account objects, one is a relation o.Account and the other is lookup - o.Partner_Account__C.

Thanks

Comment: [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) is well worth studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have introduced a new Lookup relation from Opportunity to Account as `Partner_Account__c`, first check the relation API name by generating a WSDL (***Settings > Develop > API > Generate WSDL***). Then use below code(it's assuming the relation as `Partner_Account__r` )

```
SELECT o.Id, o.Name, o.AccountId, o.Partner_Account__r.Id, o.Partner_Account__r.Name FROM Opportunity o
```

`Partner_Account__r.Id`, `Partner_Account__r.Name` are giving you the Partner Account Id, Name respectively